# Can .obj files be fractured properly?

Tags: objects

When I import an .obj file and fracture it, it doesn't fracture the object into random pieces like a cube would be fractured. Am I missing a step? Or can .obj's not be fractured like a cube?

Comment: Complex objects fracture differently. Most likely it is not because of being a .OBJ. If it is formed with Tris, that could be an important factor.

Comment: Try running a tris to quads on your mesh before fracturing, `Alt J`. Also an example of the mesh (image etc) you are trying to break would help in giving you a better answer/alternative.

Comment: Even non obj. Files  can be very difficult to fracture. Try cleaning it up by following this tutorial:  https://youtu.be/iAsV_Lh8CSQ

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I ran a tris to quads and got the same result. I did however figure out how to fracture this same .obj in Cinema4D. Here is a screen shot of the helmet .obj I am working with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ellh5grkgc53647/Helmet%20mesh.png?dl=0